# How can I backup and restore MongoDB by using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Does **pymongo** provide an **API** to enable a backup or export of collections and rows?

Comment: well, I meant using pymongo driver in python instead of mongodump/mongorestore commands...

Comment: PyMongo driver essentially just binds those MongoDB commands, so the root question of yours goes back to MongoDB docs, then look for associated PyMongo binding methods/functions for in-Python implementation details/examples.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I'll read the documentation once more. :) I'm non-English-speaker. And I'm sorry for my poor English, so I cannot express my question exactly.

Comment: What language do you speak? There is a list of translations available to the official documentation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/translation/

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this question in two parts

- Does pymongo provide an API to enable a backup or export of
  collections and rows?

As of now, No. It does not provide a binding method for backup/mongodump

- Can one use pymongo to enable a backup or export of collections and
  rows?

Yes.
lets assume we have a collection col with the following documents in it

```
{
   'price':25,
   'name':'pen'
},
{
   'price':20,
   'name':'pencil'
},
{
   'price':10,
   'name':'paper'
},
{
   'price':25000,
   'name':'gold'
}
```

Our aim is to backup all documents which satisfy the condition that their price is less than 100.
Using pymongo's find function. this can be done by

```
db.col.find({'price':{'$lt': 100}})
```

The above code returns a cursor object. All the documents that we need for the backup is in  that cursor object.

A simple way to insert all the documents will be to recursively call the documents one by one and to insert them.

But a far better method is to use the list() on the cursor and to insert all the documents in one go.

```
cursor = db.col.find({'price':{'$lt': 100}})
db.backup.insert(list(cursor))
```

The backup collection's content will be

```
{
   'price':25,
   'name':'pen'
},
{
   'price':20,
   'name':'pencil'
},
{
   'price':10,
   'name':'paper'
}
```

If there is no requirement to limit the entries to the backup. One can use an empty find()

```
cursor = db.col.find()
db.backup.insert(list(cursor))
```